# combine two "unrelated" fields in form

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning PHP and MySql, and learning it by creating my own simple BLOG with CMS. I am running into a problem here though.

I have a page called `edit_cat.php`. This is for editing the category created earlier.

My DB table looks likes this:

```
 cat_id   |   cat_title   |   parent_id
 --------------------------------------
 1           Comedy               0
 2           Standup              1
 3           Music                0
 4           Film music           3
```

When editing the post I want the user (*which will be me*), to be able to select a different parent category.

```
<?php

  $cat_id=$_GET['id'];

  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id=:cat_id");      
  $result->bindParam(':cat_id', $cat_id);
  $result->execute();
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<div class="col-md-8">

  <h2>Edit Category</h2>

  <?php 
    if(isset($succes_update)){
      echo $succes_update; 
    }
  ?>

  <form class="form-inline" action="" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo     $cat_id; ?>">

    Category Title<br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title" value="<?php echo $row['cat_title']; ?>"><br>

    Category sub Title<br>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="sub_cat_title"><?php echo $row['sub_cat_title']; ?></textarea><br>

    Parent Category<br>
    <select name="parent_id">
      <option selected><?php echo $row['parent_id'];?></option>
      <?php
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM categories");
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){   
          echo "<option>" . $row['parent_id'] . "</option>"; 
        }
      ?>
    </select>

    <br><br><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  </form>

</div>
```

On this piece:

```
echo "<option>" . $row['parent_id'] . "</option>";
```

I want the the `parent_id`, but also the `cat_title` related to the `parent_id` to be shown. This is so, so that it is easier to work with (*title/name works better then a number*).

Anyone an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT parent_id, cat_title FROM categories");
$result->execute();
while($row = $result->fetch()){   
echo "<option value = '".$row['parent_id']."'>" . $row['cat_title'] . "</option>"; 
}
?>
```

No need for `DISINCT` now, as your primary key `cat_id` will ensure every row is unique, (provided it is a primary key). You can use a `while` loop rather than a `for` here, which is much cleaner, as you don't need a counting variable.

Answer (score 1):

Update the select query to

```
SELECT (parent_id,cat_title) FROM categories
```

Then when looping thought your rows, set a value to each option

```
"<option value=\"$row['parent_id']\">".$row['cat_title']."</option>"
```

Comment: that doenst work in any way... what were you trying to say ?

Comment: Look at Martin Shutt's answer, that's what I was going for